# How to set default nice value for a particular process that is started by launchd?

Tags: launchd, command-line

I want to set the custom priority level (i.e. [`nice`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix))) to a particular program as the default priority level. The tricky thing is that the process is not started by me but by background processes not under my control. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have root access, then renice will work, well on most processes.

Comment: But renice is adapting the nice value of a running process, isn't it? I asked about a default nice value (especially to not need to individually renice it over and over again) for processes whose starts and stops are not under my control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section 5 man page for *launchd.plist* -- we can specify the *nice* value in the config plist for that process.  If the process is kicked off by something other than launchd itself, then... we may be out of options.